# Adding UITextView to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

i tried to add UITextView to swiftUI because there are things that TextEditor isn't capable of doing. Here's how I built it

```
struct TextViewSwift : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Testing UITextView"
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView
    
}
```

So I test it out with UILabel (because I want to make sure that the code is working when doing with other UIkit component)

and turns out when I debug the view, not even the UITextView appear, is it a bug within the SwiftUI it self or am I missing something? Thank you

[Only UILabel appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0pEo.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181467/12299030?

Comment: i've read and implement it, still no

Answer (score 0):

Just need a Text view? Try this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextArea: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            if text.isEmpty {
                Text(placeholder)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.placeholderText))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .padding(.vertical, 12)
            }
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .padding(4)
        }.font(.body)
    }
}
```

Comment: there are things that TextEditor is not capable at this point, this does not answer my question